# How to find columns/tables with certain row values inside it

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to fetch all the table name with certain column value inside it. For example, table A has 3 columns, one of these columns has the value 'testvalue'
table b has 6 columns, one of these columns has the value 'testvalue'
I want to get table a and b names, is there any query to do this?

Comment: Please read [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: K thank you. I've found my answer here
http://vyaskn.tripod.com/search_all_columns_in_all_tables.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all tables with a specific column name.

```
SELECT table_name, column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE column_name = 'testvalue'
```